# How To Get the Median Of n odd elements using quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, median

Can anyone explain how to improve the quicksort algorithm for finding the median of n odd numbers and what will be the worst case scenario for that algorithm? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm